# How to find whether iphone device connected to 3G /Wifi using Reachability

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, reachability

Can any one get me idea to find whether iphone device connected to 3G /Wifi  using Reachability.kindly get me some samples / URL's .im new in this iphone development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to start from the Rechability example from Apple
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/

Comment: but can u get me where to find the 3g?

Answer (score 0):

firstly add SystemConfiguration.framework to your project

```
//Class.h
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

- (BOOL)connected;
```

//Class.m

```
- (BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
Then, I use this whenever I want to see if I have a connection:

if (![self connected]) {
    // Not connected
} else {
    // Connected. Do some Internet stuff
}
```